# Which is the INT limit when I create a shared memory (shmop_open) in the KEY? (PHP)

Tags: php, ipc, shared-memory, ipcs

When I created a shared memory segment, I used an Integer for the shared memory key.  Now, I need to know the limit in the int number for this key.

I know the limit in int32 is 2147483647 and the limit in int64 is 9223372036854775807

If I create a shared memory with the number 9223372036854775807 and 9223372036854775800, the key reference is 0xffffffff and 0xfffffff8.

I think that the `ipcs -m` response, doesn't show all the hex digits.  What is the limit, and how do I confirm that `ipcs -m` works as it should?

Comment: the silence indicates how often php programmers actually use shard memory functions

Comment: maybe it is a advanced topic for many php programmers

Comment: XDDD LOL!!! usually php functions correspond to linux/posix functions... for example shmop_open corresponds to https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/shm_open.3.html maybe you can ask for C/C++ using those calls and answer will be the same...